# SoftRaid 3x2TB SATA?

Tags: ubuntu, hard-disk, raid, software-raid, vps

I recently took a new dedicated server ovh whose description is: `SoftRaid 3x2TB SATA` but I'm not sure I understand the meaning. I suppose there are `3 physical 2TB` disks so I would tend to assume it is `RAID 5` but if it was, we would end up with a `4TB` disk and not `2TB`.

Can someone explain to me what type of RAID is `SoftRaid 3x2TB SATA?`
Thank you in advance.

Comment: In my experience "dedicated" may have many meaning. You should ask ovh representative, however, you likely have a LUN (Logical Unit Number) from a SAN (Storage Appliance Network), that is a part from a pool. OVH will not bother managing many small 2T disk.